# Will libdrm-nouveau2 library conflict with proprietary nvidia-346 driver?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg, nouveau

I recently installed the nvidia-346 driver from ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa because prior versions of the nvidia driver in the official repositories were not compatible with my Nvidia Geforce GTX 970 graphics card.

I was about to update my packages today when I noticed certain packages that were about to be upgraded:

```
dpkg intel-gpu-tools libdpkg-perl libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0
  libwayland-server0 steam-launcher
```

Several of these packages seem to have something to do with graphics rendering and I'm very worried about libdrm-nouveau2 library.  Will updating any of these packages override the proprietary driver or the blacklisting of the nouveau driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You very probably also have an Intel card on-board and these are Intel upgrades (which xorg-edgers provides too)

I've applied them as I'm running Hybrid Intel-NVidia and had no ill effects, but as you're running on nVidia drivers only, these drivers are only being installed because they're there already!

That being said: [take a system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) *first* (you've just been promoted to user type 4) and *afterwards apply these upgrades*.  If anything goes wrong, just restore the system backup and hold those packages at their current level.  (thought that's highly unlikely as you're running pure nVidia)

Comment: But the thing is, I'm not running in hybrid intel-nvidia mode.  I'm not running an integrated graphics card.  This is a desktop--I'm using the Nvidia GTX Geforce 970.  The update did install without an issue though.

Comment: Answer adjusted to your use-case.  Please don't forget to accept the answer as valid so that the next user can benefit from your question too!  ;-)